# Python Permission Denied when running from remote powershell

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I am trying to execute a Python script on a remote machine using powershell, ie.

```
powershell ". <computer>\path\to\script.ps1; Run-Remote -computerName <computer> -scriptPath 'path\to\pystuff.py'"
```

Where Run-Remote is a wrapper for `Invoke-Command`. I have set up the `Invoke-Command` to use `-Credential` with an admin user.

When executing this command, I get a nice Errno 13: Permission Denied when it tries to run `python path\to\pystuff.py`, however if I remote in manually as that same admin user and run the python script there, it works no problem.

Am I missing some important security features of Powershell? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the python script doing anything on other computers? If so I would expect that it is a double hop problem.

Comment: It is executing a script that physically sits on another machine, yes... what is a double hop problem?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/knowledgecast/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem/

Comment: Interesting, this does seem to be the issue. I tried moving the script onto the actual machine and it works. Now, is there a way around this that does not involve moving scripts around?

Comment: Yes. There are articles all over the web about how to handle it.